# How to build a MDI application based on controller/model/store/view with ExtJS 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, mdi

I want to build a MDI (multiple document interface) application that displays multiple instances of one model (i.e. users) at the same time in separate panes (here: within a tabpanel).

My normal approach would be to create a controller for each instance that contains all necessary views and stores. But as I have understood the architecture this is not possible. I can have multiple views and stores but only one controller. View creation can be done automatically by haveing a master view that contains all of the other views. But with stores it is not that easy if I do not want to use nested models/stores. So I have to create all stores by hand.

Is there really no possibility to manage all this by multi-instantiate the related controller? Or is there another elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can have as many controllers as you need, even for a single view, and for stores, why would you want to create the same store several times? Reuse in your descendant controllers/views.